# Is my code crashes because I did not set the value of head node?

Tags: python, linked-list

So the function which I am working is erase() [Erases node or nodes in list from first to, but not including last: [first, last). When last is not given, erase only first node]. I successfully did all test cases except cases when I need to delete the head node. There are no specific node.head or anything like that in this project to change it. And I am pretty sure that problem is related to head node.

(Sorry for my English it is not my first language and also I am first time working with Linked List)

Here is my code:

```py
def erase(self, first: Node, last: Node = None) -> Node:
  #Case 3 (front)
    if first.prev is self.node and last is None:
        nxt = first.next
        nxt.prev = self.node
        first.next = self.node
        first.prev = self.node
        first = None

        return nxt.next
```

The simplest example is this:

0 <-> 2

and after running erase(lst.node.next) result should be this:

2

But sadly I am not getting it (Only if the node that should be removed is head node)

Comment: In first node, what is `prev` ?

Comment: None <-> 0 <-> 2 <-> None <-> 0 <-> 2 <-> ....

Comment: If I'm reading the code correctly, nothing will happen in the first node since `first.prev` will never equal `self.node`

Comment: it does, what I am trying to do is to check first node, if it is at the beginning of the list first.prev is self.node should trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop a single node, just set the neighbor links to the opposite neighbor.

```
def erase(self, first: Node, last: Node = None) -> Node:
  #Case 3 (front)
    if last == None:  # remove first node only
       if first.next:
           first.next.prev = first.prev # link next to prev
       if first.prev:
           first.prev.next = first.next # link prev to next
       return first.next or first.prev  # return next node, else prev node
```